# Objective C Learning e-book, code error (noob)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am very new to Objective C since our business just switched over from java, so I started following the *Objective-CFundamentals.pdf e-book by Christopher K. Fairbairn, Johannes Fahrenkrug, Collin Ruffenach*

But I keep comming across alot of problems (and I know why because the book is based on iPhone 4.3 and the latest xcode is on 5, which my job requires). The one problem (which seems so simple) I am stuck on, if anyone can help I would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: I will post the code below, the code code directly from the e-book example, thus it is not me that typed it, although i followed the e-book to the letter it gives me this error and there no help in solving it inside the e-book :( THANKS for the quick response though!

The RootMasterViewControler.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootMasterViewController : UITableViewController {
NSDictionary *cityMappings;
}

@end

typedef enum PropertyType {
Unit,
TownHouse,
Mansion
} PropertyType;

typedef struct {
NSString *address;
PropertyType type;
double weeklyRentalPrice;
} RentalProperty;
```

RootMasterViewControler.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return ARRAY_SIZE(properties);
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
}
RentalProperty *details = &properties[indexPath.row];
int indexOfComma = [details->address rangeOfString:@","].location;
￼￼NSString *address = [details->address
                       substringToIndex:indexOfComma];
NSString *city = [details->address
                  substringFromIndex:indexOfComma + 2];
cell.textLabel.text = address;
if ([city isEqual:@"Clifton"])
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mountain.png"];
else if ([city isEqual:@"Sumner"])
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sea.png"];
else
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"city.png"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rents for $%0.2f per week",
 details->weeklyRentalPrice];
return cell;
}
```

Error 1) @*address "Expected expression"
Error 2) @cell.textLabel.text "Use of undeclared identifier 'address'

i know next to nothing about Obj-C and I'm following the Obj-C learning e-book to the letter. Thanks for any help.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/252/screenshot20120113at443.png/

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the _code_ and the error messages; this is completely unsearchable for anyone else who might experience this problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys, I have edited my question with the code.

Comment: @ Galaxas0 below: Yes the ebook explains bases on iOS 4.3 but I'm using xcode IDE with iOS 5 selected.

Comment: You should make sure to copy/paste the code from what you have entered in your xcode project itself, not from the book. Otherwise if you made a small mistake in following the book, no one will be able to know. Also, I guess we can assume you aren't using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)?

Comment: How can I enable such? But yes, for the moment assume I am not using ARC.

Comment: I have turned ARC on, I am receiving 100's of erros with Auto-generated code that I got at the time I created the project... weird.

Comment: I have given up on this useless e-book, I will find another source for good learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call details->address like it was a C struct; Objective-C objects are more than C structs. You would need to use [details getAddress] if you had a setter/getter/property declared, or details.address to access address in the details class.

Second, you can't declare RentalProperty *details = &properties[indexPath.row]; like this, since you're asking a pointer to store a reference. You need to drop the &; again, Objective-C objects are far more than C structs.

Third of all, a simple error, you mean to say that the book explains based on iOS 4.3, but iOS's latest version is 5. You said Xcode's latest version - Xcode is the IDE, and iOS is the mobile OS.